# snowflake: how to search users whose email is?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake how to select a user with email id

I am trying

```
show users;
select "email" from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) limit 1;
```

this shows "test@example.com"

then i try

```
show users;
select "email" from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) WHERE "email" = "test@example.com" limit 1;
```

i get

```
SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 72 invalid identifier '"test@example.com"'
```

how to search for the email.. in users in snowflake

Comment: String literals in SQL are delimited with apostrophe (') double quotes (") are used for identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with a single quoted value.

```
show users;
select "email" from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) WHERE "email" = 'test@example.com' limit 1;
```

Also, if you have access to ACCOUNT_USAGE, you could query the USERS-view there: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/users.html

Answer (score 0):

String literals should be wrapped with `'`:

```
SELECT "email" 
FROM table(result_scan(last_query_id())) 
WHERE "email" = 'test@example.com' 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: your answer is also right